# Why does JsonConvert.SerializeObject fail when called from a nested task?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a console program which starts a long running task, which in turn starts 4 x long running tasks. By long running I mean all these tasks are supposed to run indefinitely.

However, calling JsonConvert.Serialize from any of the nested tasks crashes the app silently, without any error messages.

I've recreated this behaviour with a simple console program:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string ATestProperty { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var outerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var nestedTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inside nestedTask");
                var testClass = new TestClass { ATestProperty = "Hi from test class" };
                var serialisedClass = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testClass);
                Console.WriteLine(serialisedClass);
            });
        });
        
        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
    }
}
```

This prints

```
DONE
Inside nestedTask
```

If I debug and step through the code, the program terminates right after executing

```
var serialisedClass = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testClass);
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, perhaps it is a combination of a task + serialisation behaviour that I'm not aware of. I've tried `System.Text.Json` to serialise my data too with the same results.

Comment: Really strange that it stops after debugging even if you properly put `async`s and `await`s. Tested on Rider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can add Task.WaitAll(Task task) after each block of nested task.

Example:

 var outerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var nestedTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inside nestedTask");
                var testClass = new TestClass { ATestProperty = "Hi from test class" };
                var serialisedClass = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testClass);
                Console.WriteLine(serialisedClass);
            });
            Task.WaitAll(nestedTask);
            
        });
        Task.WaitAll(outerTask);
        
        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done it but could you elaborate as to why this works?

Comment: @LePrinceDeDhump That's because we are waiting actually all inner tasks to complete. Without code in my example parent code does not wait to finish inner code, so it leads that actually inner code's result does not displayed.
Update: you can also use:
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { // something }, , TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent); 
And then for parent do: parentTask.Wait();